Why don't dissolved Na ions react in water the same way pure sodium metal does?
Many are familiar with the classic chemistry experiment where a chunk of pure Na metal is dropped into a beaker of water and explodes.
We are all also familiar with the concept that NaCl salt dissolves in water, because the polar water molecules break apart the Na and Cl ions present.
But what I don't understand is, when NaCl is dissolved into Na and Cl separately, why doesn't the Na ion, having been separated from Cl, react the same way that pure Na metal does?  And when the water is boiled/evaporated out, how is it that NaCl always recombine before any explosions happen (or dangerous Cl gas escapes)?

Your way or writing chemical equations, while relatively good-looking and consistent, differs from the one accepted at this site. Now to the point: $\ce{NaCl}$ is never dissolved into $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ separately. If that's the concept you are familiar with, then it's about time to unfamiliarize yourself from it. Instead, $\ce{NaCl}$ dissociates into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$, which is a very, very, different thing.

Because they're  already "reacted".

You are kind of asking why wooden ash does not burn the same way as wood burns.

sodium reacts with water to give a redox reaction in which Na oxidises to Na+ and H2O is reduced to H2.

This redox reaction takes place because delta G for it is negative.  (can be predicted on the basis of electrochemical series and standard reduction potential values)
In NaCl, sodium is already oxidised to Na+ and no further oxidation can take place and no reaction occurs

